# Invalid Hook Call when using styled-components in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Can't get styled components to work. All I'm doing is

> npx create-react-app

and writing this in my App.js file:

```
import './App.css';
import styled from "styled-components";

const Main = styled.main`
  font-family: "Clear Sans", "Helvetica Neue", Arial, sans-serif;

  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items:  center;

  width: 100%;
  max-width: 500px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  `;

  const Header = styled.header`
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;

  border-bottom: 1px solid #3a3a3c;

  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 3.6rem;
  letter-spacing: 0.2rem;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  `;

function App() {
  
  return (
    <div>
      <Main>
        <Header>My App</Header>
      </Main>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

When I run the app i get this wall of errors

```
Warning: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:
1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app
See https://reactjs.org/link/invalid-hook-call for tips about how to debug and fix this problem. react.development.js:209
Warning: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:
1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app
See https://reactjs.org/link/invalid-hook-call for tips about how to debug and fix this problem. react.development.js:209
Uncaught TypeError: dispatcher is null
    useDebugValue React
    O StyledComponent.js:116
    O StyledComponent.js:174
    React 11
    workLoop scheduler.development.js:266
    flushWork scheduler.development.js:239
    performWorkUntilDeadline scheduler.development.js:533
react.development.js:1659
Warning: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:
1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app
See https://reactjs.org/link/invalid-hook-call for tips about how to debug and fix this problem. react.development.js:209
Warning: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:
1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app
See https://reactjs.org/link/invalid-hook-call for tips about how to debug and fix this problem. react.development.js:209
Uncaught TypeError: dispatcher is null
    useDebugValue React
    O StyledComponent.js:116
    O StyledComponent.js:174
    React 12
    workLoop scheduler.development.js:266
    flushWork scheduler.development.js:239
    performWorkUntilDeadline scheduler.development.js:533
react.development.js:1659
The above error occurred in the <styled.main> component:

O@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:4518:8
div
App

Consider adding an error boundary to your tree to customize error handling behavior.
Visit https://reactjs.org/link/error-boundaries to learn more about error boundaries. react-dom.development.js:18687
Uncaught TypeError: dispatcher is null
    useDebugValue React
    O StyledComponent.js:116
    O StyledComponent.js:174
    React 9
    workLoop scheduler.development.js:266
    flushWork scheduler.development.js:239
    performWorkUntilDeadline scheduler.development.js:533
react.development.js:1659
    useDebugValue React
    O StyledComponent.js:116
    O StyledComponent.js:174
    React 9
    performConcurrentWorkOnRoot self-hosted:1406
    workLoop scheduler.development.js:266
    flushWork scheduler.development.js:239
    performWorkUntilDeadline scheduler.development.js:533
```

Any ideas how to fix this? React and ReactDOM should be up to date. I'm not even using any hooks.

I expected the styled-components to show up correctly, instead I get an empty page with the errors described above in the browser console.

Heres package.json

```
    {
  "name": "wordle",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.5",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: There's no styled-components dependency in your package.json

Comment: You have called react hook inside a not a valid react component.
Just check for this issue.

Comment: I believe this answer might help here too:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/75399930/4508395