# Importing/exporting styled components in React causes invalid hook calls

Tags: reactjs, styled-components

I am working on a React project (react@18.2.0, styled-components@5.1.1) that has been set up to use styled-components so that commonly used components are exported from a common/styled.js file, but that causes a great amount of invalid hook call errors.

Right now, it looks something like this:

```
export const ExampleButton = styled.button`
  color: white;
`;
```

And then those styled componets are imported where needed, like this:

```
import { ExampleButton, SomeComponent, AnotherComponent } from '../common.styled';
```

I know they invalid hook calls are caused by this export/import setup, because the error message for one particular styled component goes away when I remove it from common/styled.js and instead paste it locally everywhere it's needed, so that instead of this:

```
import { ExampleButton } from '../common.styled';

const ExampleComponent = () => {
  return (
    <div>
       <ExampleButton>Hello</ExampleButton>
    </div>
  );
};
```

I do this:

```
import styled from 'styled-components';

const ExampleComponent = () => {
  const ExampleButton = styled.button`
    color: white;
  `;

  return (
    <div>
      <ExampleButton>Hello</ExampleButton>
    </div>
  );
};
```

So that works, but it's not really a viable solution, because I would have to paste the same code everywhere, not just ExampleComponent, and doing that for the whole project would result in a massive amount of code repetition.

What is the right way to create a solution similar to common/styled.js here in a way that doesn't break the Rules of Hooks?

Comment: Please elaborate on what kind of invalid hook call error you get.

Comment: The error messages say "Warning: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component." and the stack trace always contains a file where a styled component is being defined outside of the body of a function component, which in this case is most often ./src/common/styled.js.

Comment: And which hook is it complaining about?

Comment: The stack trace refers to the useRef hook in one line: `useRef @ react.development.js:1629`. Other than that, and some general blurb about invalid hook calls, the error message doesn't really elaborate much.

Comment: Does it happen with React 17 as well?

Comment: Rolling back to React 17 made the error messages go away, so I'm going with that for the time being. Would be nice to have a more future proof solution but this is good enough for now. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It seems that there had been an issue between some older versions of styled-components and React 18 that have been [solved in v5.3.1](https://styled-components.com/releases#v5.3.1).
https://github.com/styled-components/styled-components/pull/3564

Maybe upgrading styled-components to v5.3.1 or higher would solve the issue.

Comment: Thank you! Rolling back to React 17 worked at least, I'm heading home from work now but when I get back on Monday I'll try upgrading both React and styled-components to their most recent versions, I'll report if it worked.

Comment: No worries. Hope it helps.